# validation rule using LINQ

Tags: linq

It can select operators for each user and I want to check whether the input is valid or not

Here is my expected result

| level | user | operator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | - |
| 2 | B | AND |
| 2 | C | AND |
| 2 | D | - |
| 3 | E | - |

Validation rule

1. the operator must be "-" when there is 1 record in the same level
2. If there is more than 1 record in the same level, the operator must be "-" on the last record and it must select "AND"/ "OR" on other records

How to validate it using LINQ and C#?

Comment: It would help if you could show some code. It looks like you are asking for `items.GroupBy(x => x.level).All(g => g.Last().operator="-' && g.Count(x => x.operator='-') == 1)` Is that what you mean?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you stuck? Please amend your question to include the code.

Comment: Thanks Ian
I have already fixed the problem. It helps me a lot